# Java properties: best practices?

Tags: java, application-settings, properties-file

Scenario: application has an algorithm where some optimizations can be enabled. By default some are on, some are off. Is there a convenient way of implementing some kind of global property system in Java?

Requirements:

- must be easy two run multiple instances of the program with different settings
- accessible from each class (without passing any objects if possible)
- settable via commandline arguments e.g. -DenableOptimizationX
- "standard" way / easily understandable for users

Alternatives:

- [built-in global properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html), e.g. `-DenableOptimizationX=true` and `System.getProperty("foo.bar.enableOptimizationX")`
- [built-in property files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)
- [environment variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) `System.getenv("enableOptimizationX")`
- class with static variables
- instance that contains settings and is passed, loaded via settings file/arguments
- ... ?

Which of these (or other) seems the best solution for this scenario?

Comment: The fact that it should be accessible from anywhere is, IMO, a sign of a design problem. If the parameters are for a specific algorithm, why would all the other classes have to access these properties?

Comment: @JBNizet I would like a simple way of getting properties for the algorithm. Do you have any suggestions for a better design? How would you implement a general property system for this kind of scenario?

Answer (score 3):

1. Keep properties in .prop files. I think this is better than command line arguments because

> 1. it makes easy to look what all properties are being used.
> 2. what is their current value,
> 3. each deployment environment can have their own properties values(ex. qa, prod)
> 4. you can logically group properties in different files.

2. Create a class PropertyFactory. Have a private static final member `propertiesMap`. In this class in static block initalize `propertiesMap` with values from all properties file.
   You can use `propertiesMap` now from anywhere in code.
3. To make it easy for end user, you can give one more option to user to specify property values in command line arguments. And in your static block, handle it. Override in map if user has provided value for some property.
4. You can access it  as

   PropertiesFactory.getPropertiesMap().get("key");

Update

5. You want values to be changed runtime. But thats not possible with vm arguments/command line arguments/ system enviornments. These values are fixed once program execution starts. So this is not possible in stand alone java application.

If you want values to be update able , then propertiesMap needs to be mutable. You will need to run this program on server, where instance of propertiesMap is maintained and you can put method on this map when you want to override value of one of its key.

Comment: So you would access it using `PropertyFactory.getProperties().getProperty("foo");`? But what if you quickly want to change it when running the program? e.g. run the algorithm in parallel with different settings? I'll add this to my requirements.

Comment: I mean that I want to run multiple instances of the program with different arguments, this is possible, but what is a good way of doing this?

Comment: You could use @Pranalee 's solution, but store the properties in a "map of maps". (accessing properties via `PropertyFactory.getProperties("ProgramInstanceXY").getProperty("foo");`). Nevertheless I would strongly recommend to pass the properties around instead of accessing them statically.

Comment: If you have fixed set of instances running, you can have properties file for each. or you can allow users to pass file name from command line arguments.

Comment: @slartidan why is it generally better do pass them around instead of static access?

Comment: Too many static variables can eat your permgen space and if you put values in java file, every time you need to change values, you need to compile code again.

Comment: Static variables are only available once per virtual machine. This is causing problems when trying to scale the application (i.e. running several instances). PS: and can cause memory leaks, as mentioned by @Pranalee

Comment: I have seen programs, e.g. Apache Hadoop, where you can manipulate the settings using a properties file, containing entries for variables such as `foo.bar.optimization1`, and at the same time you can pass command line arguments. Is there an easy way of obtaining this behaviors myself without implementing all logic behind this? I also wonder whether this method would internally use a map, as has been suggested, or whether variables are manipulated directly. Any ideas?